# Если содержимое в блоке выходит за пределы, перенести в другой

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery

У меня есть блок page в виде страницы для печати.

```css
.page{
    max-width: 21cm;
    max-height: 29.7cm;
    min-width: 21cm;
    min-height: 29.7cm;
    padding: 0.5cm;
    margin: 0.5cm auto;
    border: 1px #D3D3D3 solid;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background: white;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
```

```html
<div class="page" style="font-size: 14px;">
  тут содержимое и блок в котором можно менять содержимое
  <div class="edit" contenteditable></div>
  и тут продолжение
</div>
```

Когда пользователь изменяет содержимое блока edit, если контент выходит за пределы родительского блока page, создать еще блок page и то, что вышло за пределы этого блока, перенести это туда. Как это сделать?

Comment: Предполагается только текстовый ввод? Потому что, если прямо здесь на странице выделить содержимое и попытаться его вставить, то оно вставиться со всеми стилями и разметкой, что поломает страницу полностью.

Comment: нет, не только. Как написано выше, перед блоком и после блока, который можно редактировать есть текст

Comment: текст до и после - полбеды. Попробуйте сделать то, что я описал и поймёте весь масштаб проблемы. Пока даже мыслей нет...

Comment: Можно описать чуть подробней, немного не понятно)

Comment: прямо здесь, на этой странице, чтобы не искать какой-либо текст, выделите произвольные символы и скопируйте в буфер. Затем запустите свой код в примере и попытайтесь вставить из буфера в редактируемый див. Думаю, что Вы, как и я захватите все флексы, марджины, паддинги и тд. Как их разбивать - ума не приложу.

Comment: ага... понял, спасибо

Comment: то, что Вы поняли - это хорошо. Плохо, что вопрос интересный, а решения нет, пока даже в перспективе :(

Comment: Я так понял, нужно заранее получить редактированный текст, и уже вывести его?

Comment: в общем, текст, который будет вводиться, должен быть текстом - тогда можно отследить/разорвать/перенести (даже с тем содержимым, что идёт за ним - _"и тут продолжение"_). В ином случае, разбор вставки настолько усложнит код, что сами не рады будете.

Comment: Если это для последующего вывода на печать, то, есть какие-то свойства/методы, но вспомнить не смогу, ибо никогда не нужно было.

Comment: https://dropmefiles.com/PAIOk
Здесь видно, что на 1м скриншоте, как загружается страница по умолчанию, а во второй после изменения пользователя. То есть нужно получить каким-то образом текст, который выходит за пределы родительского блока и его вставить в следующую страницу

Comment: думаю, что это может как-то помочь. Попробуйте разобраться - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/page-break-after

Comment: полезное свойство. Но есть какой-то способ получить текст, который вышел за пределы родительского блока?

Comment: если это именно текст, то несложно получить через JS/

Comment: да, как с помощью js получить этот текст? вот это интересно)

Comment: может кто подскажет, но я не сегодня, ибо второй час ночи уже у меня...

Comment: а, понял. Ну, в любом случае спасибо)

Comment: нужно точно определить цель - это для последующей печати или просто нужно разделить по блокам с фиксированными размерами. Укажите/уточните это в вопросе.

Comment: Хорошо, сейчас сделаю